# SQL update function

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-update

I'm working with sql requests in a php file, but i have a problem. My get fonction works :

```
if( isset($_POST['week']) && !empty($_POST['week']) && isset($_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['location']))
     {
         $week = $_POST['week'];
         $location = $_POST['location'];
         $sql = 'SELECT *
         FROM myDataBaseName
         WHERE myDataBaseName_week='.$week.'
         AND myDataBaseName_location="'.$location.'"';
     }
```

My update function doesn't look to work :

```
if (isset($_POST['week']) && !empty($_POST['week']) && isset($_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['number']) && !empty($_POST['number']))
    {
         $week = $_POST['week'];
         $location = $_POST['location'];
         $numberForUpdate = $_POST['number'];

         $sql = 'UPDATE *
         FROM myDataBaseName
         SET myDataBaseName_numbers ='.$numberForUpdate.'
         WHERE myDataBaseName_week='.$week.'
         AND myDataBaseName_location="'.$location.'"';
    }
```

Can anyone help me to get a correct update function please ?

Thanks !

Comment: you should consider using mysqli_real_escape_string before concatenation `$week = $_POST['week'];` into `$week = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['week']);`

Comment: 'UPDATE myDataBaseName
         SET myDataBaseName_numbers ='.$numberForUpdate.'
         WHERE myDataBaseName_week='.$week.'
         AND myDataBaseName_location="'.$location.'"';

Comment: The syntax is `UPDATE table SET...` and not `UPDATE * FROM table SET...` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE myDataBaseName
         SET myDataBaseName_numbers ='.$numberForUpdate.'
         WHERE myDataBaseName_week='.$week.'
         AND myDataBaseName_location="'.$location.'"';
```

and not

```
$sql = 'UPDATE *
         FROM myDataBaseName
         SET myDataBaseName_numbers ='.$numberForUpdate.'
         WHERE myDataBaseName_week='.$week.'
         AND myDataBaseName_location="'.$location.'"';
```

[Reference for update in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

However you need to know it's not safe method to update data. You should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injections and here data could be anything user enter in form.

Comment: It doesn't look like to work more, that's why I used * From. I think prepared statements are not obligatory because this requests are filled with an smartphone application. I check the correct fill in into my app code

Comment: @user1833903 It's hard to say what doesn't work if you didn't show any errors. If you are sure it's SQL error you should use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create your database structure and data and edit the question

Comment: It's working. I don't know why when I put the url in my navigator it works with the first function and not with the second but in the app it works !